# Optimal distance to the blowtorch nozzle to make a cup of water boil

Tags: temperature, water, heat-conduction

I have a propane torch and a steel cup of water that I want to boil.

Should I put the cup at the tip of the flame, or push it right into the flame to boil faster?

[image: Just the tip]

[image: Push it into the flame]

Yes, I know that the hottest point of the flame is the tip. I don't need to burn a hole in my cup, I need to make the water inside boil, and any part of the flame will be hotter than $100°C$, but the tip of the flame heats a smaller surface area.

A [similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/194901/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-use-a-blow-torch) was already asked, but it has no proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely the larger surface area would help, but both are going to be pretty inefficient.  A lot of the energy from combustion will be removed by convection as air currents are driven up the side of the cup.  I think it would be easier to test the two alternatives (time the same volume and same temperature water in the same ambient temperature environment in calm conditions to boiling) than it would be to calculate anything based on the flame characteristics.

If you could rearrange things so that the flame heated the bottom of the cup (perhaps by placing it on a triangular stand with a space in the middle, then some of the convection losses would be reduced.  I think you'd find an improvement in the heating rate.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will need another wooden stump to set up the cup like that, unfortunately this is over the budget of wooden stumps that I have here, so I'm going to use the inefficient way, at least until I'll get a proper gas burner.